# GroupBy and flatten pyspark dataframe based on column value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
amount1 amount2 period  customerId
3.0     4.0     weekly   12345
23.0    26.0    monthly  12345
201.0   190.0   yearly    12345
3.1     4.2     weekly   56789
21.2    36.5    monthly  56789
231.0   191.0   yearly    56789
```

I'd like to flatten it like this :

```
weekly_amt1 weekly_amt2 monthly_amt1 monthly_amt2 yearly_amt1 yearly_amt2 customerId
3.0         4.0         23.0         26.0         201.0       190.0       12345
3.1         4.2         21.2         36.5         231.0       191.0       56789
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this ?
I know that there is a `pivot` function, but it doesn't seem to handle pivoting on more than 1 column, and since it's expensive I don't want to pivot more than once.

Comment: Not really, how do I get the column names ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to find an answer:

```
def pivot_mult(df, cols):
    mydf = df.select('customerId').drop_duplicates()
    for c in cols:
        mydf = mydf.join(df.withColumn('combcol',\
               F.concat(F.lit('{}_'.format(c)),df['period']))\
                .groupby('customerId').pivot('combcol').\
                         agg(F.first(c)),'customerId')
    return mydf
```